# Count rows and columns query in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, count

How to count rows and columns in a MySql database from Visual Studio C#?

I want to use the number of columns, and the number of rows as integers.

```
conn.Open();
private MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DT_RSSI_VALUES_GRID_" + gridDesc + ";", conn);
int x = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Error 13  Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader' to 'int'

Comment: `ExecuteReader` returns a datareader which you can read the results.  A SELECT COUNT query is always going to only have one column

Comment: @Plutonix I can't get to read the results and turn them into int. I'm using 'int.parse(cmd.ExecuteReader().ToString());'

Answer (score 3):

You are going to want to use ExecuteScalar which returns a single value, like:

```
int x = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Comment: I have already tried with `ExecuteScalar()` but it doesn't work either. It returns an object, not an integer, and it doesn't accept an int cast.

Comment: how about Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())

Answer (score 0):

Try `object x = cmd.ExecuteScalar();`